# Conditional in print statement doesn't print the rest of it. Java

Tags: java, printing, conditional-statements

So here's a simple code to adjust the right "st", "nd", "rd", "th" with the input number. *It's placed in a loop for a reason. Nevermind that.*

```
System.out.println("How many?");
int num = x.nextInt();
for(int i=1;i<=num;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the " + i);
    System.out.println(i==1? ("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th") + " number!");
}
```

when num is input as `5` here's the output:

```
Enter the 1st
Enter the 2nd number!
Enter the 3rd number!
Enter the 4th number!
Enter the 5th number!
```

Question is where's "number!" with the case "1st"??

Comment: okay thanks everyone I get it. I thought that putting `("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th")` instead of `"st":i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th"` would restrict the boundaries of the conditional. but apparently it doesn't work that way .. so putting the whole conditional in brackets would do. thank you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a pair of braces, change:

```
System.out.println(i==1? ("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th") + " number!");
```

to:

```
 System.out.println((i==1? ("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th")) + " number!");
                    ^                                         ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice the condition of your print :

```
i == 1 ? ("st") : ((i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th") + " number!")
           ^                             ^
         true                          false
```

I added parenthesis to the false part so it is easier for you to understand.

I believe what you want is :

```
(i == 1 ? ("st") : (i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th")) + " number!"
                                                      ^
              Now we add it to the result of what is returned for the condition.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(i==1? ("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th") + " number!");
```

is the source of the problem. Do you see how you have + " number!"); after the : that separates the 1st and the 2nd/3rd? You need to have this twice.

```
System.out.println(i==1? ("st number"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th") + " number!");
```

or

```
System.out.println((i==1? ("st"):(i==2? "nd":i==3? "rd":"th")) + " number!");
```

Comment: Thought I don't think that this is how the OP intended to do it - it should work as well!